# Работа с кодировками текста: data.encode('utf-8') вызывает UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, кодировка, python-2.x, unicode

Передаю по soap следующее сообщение `test`. На входе в программе получаю `��-`. Делаю `data.encode('utf-8')`, на что получаю ошибку:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Как получить свое слово слово `test` внутри программы ?

Comment: Без полного описания, как именно передаёте, ответить будет трудно, ибо `��-` не похоже на `test` ну вообще никак

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке намекает, что data уже набор байтов (откуда вы data получили?), не нужно encode использовать. Возможно наоборот decode надо вызвать, чтобы Unicode получить для вывода текста. Что значит "на входе в программу получаю"? Как именно: через sys.argv, sys.stdin, из сети, из файла? Отредактируйте вопрос и приведите `print repr(data)` с описанием откуда data берётся  и куда вы хотите data передать.

Answer (score 2):

'ascii' codec can't ...... - интерпретатор говорит, что кодировка ascii не  может ДЕКОДИРОВАТЬ

посмотри какая кодировка используется при отправке сообщения по SOAP.
нужно чтобы сообщения использовали кодировку UTF-8 (которая по умолчанию в ПИТОНЕ)

Не каждый байт содержит допустимый символ ASCII и не каждая последовательность байтов являетсяся допустимой в кодироке UTF-8 или UTF-16. Если при декодировании двоичной последовательности встретиться неожиданный байт, то произойдет выброс исключения UnicodeDecoreError.

можно и избежать исключение.

```
data.decode('UTF-8', errors='replace')
```